# What API can I use to make an Android app to detect Eddystone beacons?

Tags: android, api, altbeacon, eddystone, beacon

I read more web pages and is not clear what API is better to use to interact with eddystone API.
I need a couple of beacon, they have to work on a background service (on Android); in particular, I need the first beacon to start recording a signal and the second (more distant) to stop recording. Moreover I need that each user can set (through my app) the couple of beacon has to use as first e second. I have Kontakt.io Beacon compatible with eddystone standard and the kontakt.io provides own API too. But I would like the users, in the future, can use any kind of beacon compatible to standard Eddystone, not just kontakt.io; so I should not use kontakt.io API.

What kind of API can I use to develop my app? What is better to use for my requirements?

Answer (score 3):

The [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) is a the default choice for general purpose Eddyatone beacon detection for a number of reasons:

1. It is widely used on over 4,000 apps with 100 million+ end users.
2. It is free and open source, so it is easy to get help in forums like this.
3. It detects all Eddystone frame types including UID, URL and TLM.
4. It can do fast background detection and give distance estimates to beacons.
5. It is also compatible with other beacon types (AltBeacon, iBeacon) should you need expanded support in the future.

You can see code samples of how to use this Library with Eddystone here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html

As you note, Google also provides Eddystone APIs, which are largely focussed on integrating with their cloud services like Nearby.  Which you choose depends on your goals.  The Android Beacon Library is a more general purpose solution.

Full disclosure: I am the lead developer on the project and the most likely guy to answer your questions if and when you have them.

Comment: The code samples for eddystone (http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html) appear so easy but incomplete. For istance, I need to set the transmission power because, on my project, the beacons have to notify the android devices at distance of 1 meter about. How can I make that with Android Beacon Library?

Comment: When you say you want to configure the transmission power, are you talking about configuring the beacon settings?  If so, what manufacturer is it?

Comment: Moreover, I have some problem to Import your Library. I followed the project setup guide for eclipse, but when I import the android-beacon-library folder as an existing project in the workspace, Eclipse gave me several errors referred to "R.java" file of my project.

Comment: I think my last problem is related to min sdk version. Following the project setup guide I should set my min sdk versione to "18". I know, beacon works only with Android 4.3 or more but I want my app works also for previous Android version (of course without using beacon and bluetooth). Setting min sdk less than 18 I have some errors in my project after imported your library.

Comment: A couple of points:  (1) The library is not designed to configure beacons.  I don't know of any library that will configure beacons of multiple vendors.  Typically, beacon manufacturers supply their own proprietary SDK or app to configure beacons because there is no standard.  (2) It is common to configure the Android Beacon Library to work with older SDK versions.  See here for more info:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/backward-compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

You might use the altbeacon library

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you think is the best solution? I visit altBeacon web site but API documentation doesn't seem so clear..I didn't understand if Google provides API for eddystone...On web everybody talk about AltBeacon api..

Answer (score 0):

(Disclosure: I work on the Nearby API)

If you want to associate payloads with your beacons via [Google's Proximity Beacon API](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments) then [Nearby.Messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages) is good solution.

In Google Play Services 7.8, Nearby allows foreground scanning without adding a new platform permissions to your Manifest.

In an upcoming release of Google Play Services, we're introducing background scanning, where Nearby will initiate scans on your app's behalf and wake your app up when we find a beacon of interest with a payload. Keep on an eye on the [Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/) for the release.